# Which Java data object to use for multidimensional range matching?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, arraylist, treemap

**Project Background:**
I am writing a map tile overlay class for java that can use gdal2tile.py tiles. Basically I will end up with thousands of jpg files that are in a file structure like 
"Zoom Level/X coordinate/Y coordinate"
The coordinates are ints but will not necessarily start at 0 or 1.
I will have to search for tiles that are within a certain range to find out which ones I need to render.

**My Problem:**
I tried iterating using the file structure itself but it is wicked slow (not surprising).
I tried iterating using an ArrayList of strings of the file structure and .contains() but it seems to be even slower (not too surprising).
Optimally I would like to use a data structure that would let me choose a range on multiple dimensions so that I can call something like.

Tiles.getWhere(Zoom Level,min X,max X,min Y,maxY);

I assume that some sort of Collection or TreeMap would be the right choice but I'm not experienced enough with Java to know for sure and I'd prefer not to have to benchmark a lot of different approaches.

I could use SQLite to do it but that seems like overkill.

**My Question:**
What is the most efficient way to check for the existence of datasets given multiple dimensional constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for a map with multiple keys.

Commons-collections provides a map with multiple lookup keys:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html

a map guarantees a O(1) insertion and O(1) selection timings.

Comment: Yep, that's perfect- it meets my needs and is also flexible enough to use for later projects as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of your problem I could find out three directions to which you could aim your search next *(this is not a hand-by-hand guide but rather a out-of-the-box brain opener for a stucked situation you have faced)*:

**1)** Usage of Java built in structures. Yes, indeed, a list is the worst case of a searching method. A `Map`, as the name suggests, is far more convenient for maps. It is not only the name, but the indexing to a `Map` is signifigantly less time consuming compared to a `List`. You can imagine your map as a cube, where you have to handle about half of the dots inside it, if you use `List` and probably only a narrow layer of it when you search by indexing a Map. There is a magnitude of difference. So, my answer here: `Map` is a key word towards the correct direction (*assuming you want to do it in this way after reading on my answer)*.

**2)** Usage of a Map Server solution. This is probably too far from your approach, but entire frameworks are made for solving your type of question. An example is [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/). It has a ready made solution for the entire problem. It is a stable solution for the great big problem possibly in your hand: showing a map to a user from a source.

**3)** Sticking to the GDAL framework you were using, you could select slightly different py-file, like [gdal_proximity.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_proximity.html) and **- wow! -** you have a searching possibility in your hand! This particular one searches by a center point and a distance, but will do the stuff you need =)

There is a starting point, how I would make it. Could this serve for something?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are looking for something like an Interval Tree.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

I have implemented one of these in the past but only in one dimension. The Wikipedia reference mentions extensions to more dimensions.

Paul